# Haskell stack build error "No local directories found as children"

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When running `stack build --no-terminal --install-ghc`, I run into `Error parsing targets: No local directories found as children`. 
I can understand what it means, but why does it happen? I haven't read anywhere in the Stack manual about having to create extra directories ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What's your stack version?  Can you still reproduce this with the latest?

This means that it is parsing an argument as if it is a TARGET, but isn't finding the dir.  I think in old versions of stack, unrecognized flags would get parsed this way.  So, if you're using a command intended for newer stack, this error can happen.